# Not able to inspect element of drop down using UIAutomatorViewer

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium

I want to select options from drop down on Android but I am not able to inspect element of drop down. Also these elements are not present in hierarchy as well.

I can browse the hierarchy and inspect other controls, I can't inspect the elements of a drop down list. UIAutomatorViewer just doesn't let me to click the drop down list. Instead, it shows a blue rectangle around the element which is under the drop down list. I have tried uiautomatorviewer, hierarchyviewer as well as Appium Inspector and all three have the same problem. Is there any way to work around this?

Dropdown is also not of tag Select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to locate that element on Note previously I was using Tab 
Issue is still there on Tab but by using Note I am able to click on that element.

Thanks All for you responds

Answer (score 0):

You can use `driver.scrollToExact("Item Name")`, where Item Name is option you want to select from drop-down.

Comment: Hey I have tried this main issue is here I am not able to get locator of all options present in dropdown

Comment: why do you need locator for it? You just note the item name you want to select and do it like that