# Getting 'The Application is not responding' error while using Robotium Recorder

Tags: android, automation, appium, robotium

I want to automate one mobile native app. When I try to record a script using Robotium Recorder its giving **'The Application is not responding'** error.
[image] Where as I am able to do recording for other application.

I have also tried Appium for the same app but faced different issues like 
[Not able to inspect element of drop down using UIAutomatorViewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34989266/not-able-to-inspect-element-of-drop-down-using-uiautomatorviewer)

and [Click is not working with appium test is passing but no action is performed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35032778/click-is-not-working-with-appium-test-is-passing-but-no-action-is-performed)

So I just wanted to know is it that application issue which I am trying to automated. If yes what will be the issue for what I can ask to client.

**Other Details**
Appium Version 1.4.16.1
Java Version 1.8.0_71
Win 7 64 bit
Selenium 2.48.2

Comment: maybe you can provide details like the platform used to build the app, in case of hybrid apps, games etc people use different platforms to develop the applications which might not comply with your automation framework

Comment: @nullpointer I have added details above

Comment: i meant the details of the platform in which your application was built.

Comment: @nullpointer ok I will check with client and let you know

Comment: you can put the Q on-hold until then

Answer (score 0):

Application is changed now its working